# array multi_sort asc and in numeric but zero value should be last

Tags: php

Here is my sample code;

The code is working. It's just that the zero value for order field is at the first column should be on the last or basically disregard all zero and put to last.

```
array_multisort(array_column($this->products, 'order'), SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_ASC,
            array_column($this->products, 'name'), SORT_STRING, SORT_ASC,
            $this->products);
```

Comment: Sorry -  my question is how I can sort it by number but the zero value will be move on the last part of the array?

Comment: does efficiency matters to you? i mean, can we add some O(n) operations or you need some efficient thing?

Comment: Yeah.. did not understand your question. But any help would do. Would like to test it out soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you care more about efficiency than "clean code" you can use `usort`:

```
usort($this->products, function($f, $s){
   if($f->order === 0 && $s->order !== 0)
       return 1;
   else if($f->order !== 0 && $s->order === 0)
       return -1;
   else if($f->order === $s->order){
       if($f->name < $s->name) return -1;
       else if($f->name === $s->name) return 0;
       else return 1;
   }
   else {
       if($f->order < $s->order) return -1;
       else if($f->order === $s->order) return 0;
       else return 1;
   }
});
```

Example:

```
$products = [
    (object) ['order'=>0, 'name'=>'a'],
    (object) ['order'=>1, 'name'=>'a'],
    (object) ['order'=>1, 'name'=>'b'],
    (object) ['order'=>2, 'name'=>'a'],
    (object) ['order'=>3, 'name'=>'a'],
];
usort($products, function($f, $s){
    if($f->order === 0 && $s->order !== 0)
        return 1;
    else if($f->order !== 0 && $s->order === 0)
        return -1;
    else if($f->order === $s->order){
        if($f->name < $s->name) return -1;
        else if($f->name === $s->name) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }
    else {
        if($f->order < $s->order) return -1;
        else if($f->order === $s->order) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }
 });
 var_dump($products);
```

Outputs:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["order"]=>
         int(1)
    ["name"]=>
         string(1) "a"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["order"]=>
         int(1)
    ["name"]=>
         string(1) "b"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
    ["order"]=>
         int(2)
    ["name"]=>
         string(1) "a"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
    ["order"]=>
        int(3)
    ["name"]=>
        string(1) "a"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["order"]=>
        int(0)
    ["name"]=>
        string(1) "a"
  }
}
```

As you can see, the ones that has `order` equal to `0` are at the bottom

Comment: please try this, if it does not work, can you please post an input-output example?

Comment: Thank you. I just tested the code and it have the same result as above that I used. All the zeros are still on the first row and the number value greater than zero. i.e. (1,2,3,4) goes at the last row.  like for example all Order field value 0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4  - it should be 1,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0

Comment: @TylerGrey can you please post an example of  input/output expected?

Comment: @TylerGrey you are doing something else wrong, as you can see the example works as you want, copy and paste the code and you will see

Comment: Could it be because of the order and name field are on different brackets of array? Screenshot of result on my database. its actually product_name and itemPlacementnumber field https://prnt.sc/tj958q https://prnt.sc/tj95ko

Comment: @TylerGrey no, but maybe you can try using `==` instead of `===` and same for the not equal, maybe some are ints and others are strings

Comment: Thank you @Berto99 I think it works! I just changed all the operators === to ==

Comment: @TylerGrey well feel free to mark the answer as correct